# How create structure and display comments nested Spring Boot with AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, nested

I want create comments with sub comments nested, like hierarchy. I don´t know if create structure like that

**1#** First structure

```
public class Comment{

    private Long id;        

    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=true,name="parent_id")
    private Comment parent; //Parent comment

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)    
    private Set<Comment> subComments; //Sub comments
```

Or only creat that structure. **2#** Second structure

```
public class Comment{

    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    private Long parent_id;//Parent comment
```

If I create the second structure with parent_id, my json will be like this.

```
|  id  | comment  | parent |
|  1   | comment1 |    0   |
|  2   | comment2 |    1   |
|  3   | comment3 |    2   |
|  4   | comment4 |    1   |
|  5   | comment5 |    4   |
|  6   | comment6 |    4   |
|  7   | comment7 |    6   |
|  8   | comment8 |    7   |
|  9   | comment9 |    0   |
```

My problem is how to create nested comments with Spring Boot and AngularJS? What the correct structure to create and display?

I want to display comments like that. [My jsfiddle example about that](http://jsfiddle.net/f90b218t/6/).

```
Comment #1 (deepness = 0): comment 1

    Reply #4 of #1 (deepness = 1): reply comment 1

        Reply #8 of #4 (deepness = 2): reply of reply comment 3

            Reply #9 of #8 (deepness = 3): reply of reply of reply comment 3

Comment #2 (deepness = 0): comment 2

    Reply #5 of #2 (deepness = 1): reply comment 2

Comment #3 (deepness = 0): comment 3

    Reply #6 of #3 (deepness = 1): reply comment 3

    Reply #7 of #3 (deepness = 1): reply comment 3
```

Comment: Aren't you missing an @Id field?

Comment: @Rafael Corrected.